# Автозаполнение логина и пароля в всплывающем окне

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Можно как-то в коде дописать автозополнение логина и пароля в всплывающем окне, так, чтобы пользователь не вписывал данные вручную?

Ну или сделать это каким-то другим способом, чтобы пользователь не вписывал эти данные. В коде видно что я попробовал создать и открыть новый adodb.connection, но оно почему-то все равно требует пароль.

На первом скрине видно строку после которой оно требует ввести логин и пароль, на втором скрине видно всплывающее окно, куда надо вписать данные.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очень интересно... Какой смысл в защите, если программа сама сможет обойти защиту?

Comment: Наверное чтобы пользователь не имел доступа ко всей БД, а только к той информации, которую предоставляет макрос. Так как насколько я знаю, сам код макроса можно запаролить.

Comment: Вы не поняли вопрос. Если макрос будет сам вносить логин и пароль, то любой пользователь, открыв книгу, будет иметь доступ к информации, которая по задумке должна быть открыта только тому, кто введет правильный логин и пароль. Какой смысл в такой "защите"?